# LibreOffice Calc: Is there a possibility to copy a background color from another cell?

Tags: background-color, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have created a table that has a value on one column that I have used to generate a background colour (`Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Color Scale... -> Colour Scale`). Now I would like that all the row to have that colour. Is it possible to copy the background colour from another cell?

**EDIT:**

So this is my table:

[image]

And what I want is to colour all the cells from class group with the same colour as its total group.

Meaning that for the class 101 I want all the cells to have the same yellow-orange as the cell containing 592:

[image] (this is done manually)

I want this to be some kind of formula, so any change in the last column is going to change all the colours. Is it possible?

Comment: No - it is not possible also to retrieve color in any way. It is also impossible to retrieve the color in any program from LibreOffice from any table

Comment: It (currently?) is possible to get the color (see: [How can I do to get the hexadecimal color from a cell using LIbreOffice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456579/724039)). Unfortunately that does not work when conditional formatting is used.

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple workaround that effectively is a copy color operation:

1. Select the source cell. This will place the color of the cell into
   the "recently used" section of the background color tool.
2. Select the target cell.
3. Select the color from the background color tool, where it is now easy to find in the "recently used" section.

The background color tool is next to the font color tool. The above method works in libreoffice 7.3

Comment: In 7.6 at least just selecting the cell does not add the color to the "recent used" list. But if you open Format->Cell->background and "pick" the same color as it has, it will be remembered in the recent list. Thanks anyway, your answer was one haltf of the solution ;-) (+1 nevertheless )

Answer (score 2):

Set the condition of each cell in a row to be the same as the condition you used for "total_group" cell in the same row.  Meaning base the condition on the value of the "total_group" cell (Exact same condition no changes)