# How can I do to get the hexadecimal color from a cell using LIbre Office?

Tags: libreoffice

I have some cells which have a background color and I would like to get the hexadecimal color from this.

How can I do to get these hexadecimal code ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/242690/how-to-check-background-color-of-a-cell-with-a-function/

Answer (score 3):

A not very complex macro function can cope with this task.

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Option VbaSupport 1

Function getBkColor(aCell As Range) As String
    getBkColor = "#" + CreateUNOService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess").callFunction("DEC2HEX",Array(aCell.CellRange.CellBackColor))
End Function
```

[image: An example of a function call and execution result]